# In " a picture of your memories " Could this mean a picture that reminds you a happy moment in your life and makes you smile?

Tags: expressions

How can I make an expression with the least of words as the meaning above?
I am a non-native speaker and having a trouble in writing in English. 
Please help me!

Comment: Have you never "pictured" something in your mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're referring to something like 'a picture of a fond memory' or something similar.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I think it does. Did i just miss  fond part to express to that meaning? I mean should I use that (a picture of a fond memory )  like you suggested

Comment: @Jack0910 The changes made were 1) changing to the singular to specific a particular moment that the photo is of. 2) adding 'fond' to represent the happy emotions that are associated with that moment.

Comment: or are there more expressions between natives frequently used?

Comment: @Jack0910 - I can't even think of another word to run up against *fond* in an Ngram search of  "X memories".